# How do you use Web Site Administration Tool without installing VS 2010

Tags: asp.net

I am running a website using asp.net Web Site Administration Tool.

I dont want to install vs on the web server.

Is there a way around it?

Thanks

Comment: What are you planning on using it for? User Management or the fuller website management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Web Site Administration Tool is
>   included with the Microsoft Visual Web
>   Developer Web development tool.

However, this tool is just a Web.config editor, which you could just open in notepad and edit manually. Also most of the web.config settings are editable via IIS Website/Virtual Directory properties.

Comment: I belive it also creates a database in app_data

Comment: Not if you're connecting to specified instance of SQL Server/SQL Express - I've done this quite happily for some of my sites. It will create that database if any of your providers are using the default LocalHost connection string.

Answer (score 0):

If you only really want to use the Security aspects of the Web Site Administration Tool, and you have remote access to your database then you can run the application remotely - first change your web.config to use the remote database rather than the local one, and then start the tool.

You'll then be able to manage users and roles quite happily.

If you can't connect remotely to the database (for example, you're using a local file based database) then you're a little out of luck, and might have to write some admin screens yourself using methods from the Membership and Roles providers.